Rolling Total Context DAX issue
I have these tables:
DimDate = 
DATATABLE (
    "Date", DATETIME,
    "First of Month", DATETIME,
    {
        { "01-01-2024",  "01-01-2024" },
        { "01-02-2024",  "01-02-2024" },
        { "01-03-2024",  "01-03-2024" },
        { "01-04-2024",  "01-04-2024" },
        { "01-05-2024",  "01-05-2024" }
    }
)

And this Fact:
Fact = 
DATATABLE (
    "Date", DATETIME,
    "Amount", INTEGER,
    {
        { "01-01-2024",  10 },
        { "01-02-2024",  20 },
        { "01-03-2024",  30 },
        { "01-04-2024",  40 },
        { "01-05-2024",  50 }
    }
)

With a simple relationship between the two:

I have this simple measure:
Amount = sum('Fact'[Amount])

And this cumulative measure
Amount Rolling = 
VAR MNX = MINX( ALLSELECTED( 'DimDate'[Date] ), 'DimDate'[Date])
RETURN
CALCULATE (
    [Amount],
    FILTER (
        ALL( 'DimDate'[Date] ),
        'DimDate'[Date] >= MNX &&
        'DimDate'[Date] <= MAX ( 'DimDate'[Date] )
    )
)

On the canvas is the following visuals:

I want the measure to return 70 rather than 40 - so the minimum date of the slider is 01-03-2024 so I want the measure to always return the cumulative total from the minimum date of the slider - effectively the sum of this window:

I understand that the slicer for First of the month is having an impact but is there any way to adjust the DAX to give me the result I want?

two filters same page and one selected 1 april 2024, and you whant to sum another filter with range, not anyone problem, only remove your filter "1 april 2024" on de board, ;-

@JulioGadioliSoares that is the question. Both filters need to stay but the DAX needs to ignore the filter on First of Month and return the cumulative total from the Minimum filter value on DimDate[Date]

Which table is the bottom slider slicer using? Confusing that there are two date slicers on the page. Might make more sense for the slider slicer to be changed to Style After instead of Between.

@SamNseir this is a very simple representation of a much more complex situation in a report that has a live connection to a multi-billion row model - the two different slicers represent the situation in the actual production report

you don't need to create relationship between two tables
and try this to create a measure
Measure =
SUMX (
    FILTER (
        ALL ( 'Fact' ),
        'Fact'[First of Month] <= MAX ( 'Fact'[First of Month] )
            && 'Fact'[First of Month] >= MIN ( 'DimDate'[Date] )
    ),
    'Fact'[Amount]
)



Then you need to have two dimdate tables because the two slicers will affect each other.
Measure =
SUMX (
    FILTER (
        'Fact',
        'Fact'[Date] >= MIN ( 'dimdate2'[Date] )
            && 'Fact'[Date] <= MAX ( DimDate[First of Month] )
    ),
    'Fact'[Amount]
)



upped Ryan - thanks for answering - this column does not exist in the model : 'Fact'[First of Month]

which table does the date slicer come from?

the slider and the slicer both use DimDate
